# flutter route to native activity

Tags: android, flutter

I have created one native Android project and there is one simple "DemoActivity.java" and its' layout file "activity_demo.xml" inside the project.

**How can I put above "DemoActivity.java" and "activity_demo.xml" to my Flutter project and how to route to it?**

I need help and it's better to provide me a sample code, many thanks.

Comment: But why would you need to go there? If you have to perform some task consider using `MethodChannel` to perform platform specific task.